# how define routing for MVC application when get takes one nullable parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

I expect following behaviour: when calling `http://localhost:59060/api/games/`  - it returns all games, when calling `http://localhost:59060/api/games/aaa`  - it returns all games where `DeviceId = aaa`.

Currently when I call `http://localhost:59060/api/games/aaa` or  `http://localhost:59060/api/games/`, error is:

> No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI `http://localhost:59060/api/games/`
>   No action was found on the controller 'Games' that matches the request.

Controller

```
public class GamesController : ApiController
{
    private List<Game> _GamesRepository;

    public GamesController()
    {
        _GamesRepository = CreateGamesRepository();
    }

    // GET api/Games/0xa16
    public IEnumerable<Game> Get(string deviceId)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(deviceId))
        {
            return _GamesRepository;
        }
        else
        {
            return _GamesRepository.Where(x => x.DeviceId == deviceId);
        }

    }
}
```

Configuration

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}"); 

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "ControllerDefault",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "ApiDefault2",
            url: "api/{controller}/{action}/{deviceId}",
            defaults: new { action = "get", deviceId = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Model

```
public class Game
{
    public int TaskId { get; set; }
    public string SalesForceId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Thumbnail { get; set; }
    public string DeviceId { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `WebApiConfig` class, **before** the `"DefaultApi"` route you can register your route as follows:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "GetGamesRoute",
    routeTemplate: "api/games/{deviceId}",
    new { controller = "games", action = "get", deviceId = RouteParameter.Optional }
);

// This is the default route
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Also, make the `deviceId` parameter optional:

```
// GET api/Games/0xa16
public IEnumerable<Game> Get(string deviceId = null)
```